Is there a popular treatise on Ihara-Bass formula?
It's basically in the title.
Recently I had to make a lot of use of Ihara Bass in my research. So I decided to communicate this result to a broader audience (maybe a wiki article or something). But maybe there is already something like this that I was not able to see, that I may be able to use as a starting point or to focus more on non yet covered aspects.
Many thanks
